# Passing variables to JS from controller Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to pass variables from controller to js file. Here what i do:

```html
#index.html.erb
    <%= content_tag 'div', id: 'coords', data: { coords: @coords} do %>
    <% end %>

#@coords is defined in maps#index
#@coords = Map.all
```

In browser console i could easily call:

```html
$('#coords').data('coords')
# or to acces 1st object
$('#coords').data('coords')[0]
# or to acces its attribute
$('#coords').data('coords')[0].lat 
#Object {id: 1, vibration_level: 456, lat: "71.45543", lon: "53.43424", time_sent: "1994-05-20T00:00:00.000Z"…}
```

But i can not do the same in my Javascript. I get undefined on all of this calls. 
But if I inspect my code I can locate my div with data-coords:
How to make my @coords be accessible in js?

Comment: Can you please update the question the output of the view code?

Answer (score -1):

if you js file is located like so:
`app/assets/javascripts/your-js.js.erb`

then you can use your variables like so:

`<%=  @coords %>`

EDIT:

my previous answer was wrong sing the js are precompiled.
so my new answer is :
create an html 
`app/views/layouts/_page_scope.html.erb`

```
 <%
    globalPageScope = {}
    globalPageScope['coords'] = @coords if @coords
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.globalPageScope = <%= raw globalPageScope.to_json %>;
</script>
```

then you can access that variable from the js:

`globalPageScope.coords`

Comment: This answer is so wrong I would down vote it three times if I could.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel how so ? could you suggest a better one?

Comment: Assets are precompiled using a rake task so I have no idea how you expect a *controller* to be able to pass a value there depending on a request.

Comment: edited my answer. please use a more appropriate language in future cases. no one needs no harm here.

Comment: The answer is still wrong but it's hard to help OP if she/he doesn't respond to comments...